# Plotting one point in 3D matrix for all slices in 2D plane

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have `3D` matrix `(100*50*10)` and I want to plot one specific point in all slices. Let us say point `(10*6*:)`. The plot should be in `2D` plane

Example (I have this coordinate for point that I want to plot)

```
x (10*6*1) 
x (10*6*2) 
x (10*6*3) 
x (10*6*4) 
x (10*6*5) 
x (10*6*6) 
x (10*6*7) 
x (10*6*8) 
x (10*6*9) 
x (10*6*10)
```

I tried `plot (x(10,6,:))` but I got error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot(squeeze(x(10,6,:)))
```

see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html

x(10,6,:) is still a 3D matrix, and needs to be reduced to a 1D form before plotting it. This is where the squeeze function comes in.